# Laravel: Added .htaccess file, now it's throwing NotFoundHttpException

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, public

I have uploaded the laravel project onto a shared hosting:

```
~/public_html/baby/
```

baby - is the name of the folder and the project.

In order to access the web-page I needed to add the `/public` to the path, so it was like:

```
http://domain.com/baby/public
```

I've tried to remove the `/public` string from the path, end I ended up adding this `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The .htaccess file location is:

```
~/public_html/baby/.htaccess
```

And now laravel is throwing me an error, when I'm trying to reach the web-page without adding the `/public`:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException


Open: /storage/web/alexander/public_html/baby/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php

$others = $this->checkForAlternateVerbs($request);

if (count($others) > 0)
{
   return $this->getOtherMethodsRoute($request, $others);
}

   throw new NotFoundHttpException;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked in path.php if everything is set right? Probably you've to add absolute paths in it?

Comment: Laravel was not meant to be used with shared hosting out of the box. Take a look at this article to see how to make Laravel work on shared servers: http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/setup-laravel-4-in-shared-hosting-with-securing-laravel-base-file.